# How to use Matplotlib's pcolormesh with non-uniform mesh?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array X of length N, containing ALL x-positions in the XY 2D plane, an array Y of length N containing  ALL y-positions in the XY 2D plane, and an array Z of length N that I would like to plot. This variable Z is evaluated at each of the N grid points, that are non-uniformely spaced in the XY plane.

I have managed to get a decent result by creating a uniform mesh, and interpolating Z within it using scipy.interpolate.griddata and imshow. However, I should not have to do so as Z is defined at the exact XY coordinates.
Also, I can simply plot it with gnuplot using X:Y:Z, though not ideal as it does create a mesh per se.

Is there a way to re-create the mesh such that I can plot Z with pcolormesh?

Thanks.

Comment: It would really help if you'd add some dummy data, for example for a 3x3 grid.  You seem to be describing data for a scatter plot. Do you want the cells smoothly colored (`shading='gouraud'`) or uniformly colored (`shading='flat'`)?

Comment: Is your data gridded in X and Y in that many of the X and Y are repeated and if you reshaped you would have a grid?  If so, just reshape.  If not (data is randomly distributed) try `tripcolor`.

Comment: @JodyKlymak reshape would probably not work because the length of X for a given Y is not constant. Tripcolor seems to do a decent job, though the triangular mesh can sometimes be visible.

Comment: Your post is missing essential information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72035916/edit) and add more details about how your data is structured.  Note that pcolormesh works just fine for irregularly spaced grids.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a mesh can be non-uniform and non-rectangular in real space.

If the coordinates form a mesh, then you can always use `pcolormesh`, which does not require that X and Y be each equidistant, and even does not require X and Y are each monotonically increasing or decreasing. If X and Y are not monotonical, the input coordinates to pcolormesh are interpreted as cell centers, rather than cell corners. If you want the cells to be smoothly colored, use `shading='gouraud'`.

For arbitrarily scattered data, a reliable way of using `pcolormesh` is manually interpolating the scattered data into a uniform mesh. For example:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
xi = np.linspace(1,  2, 100)
yi = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 100)
zi = griddata((x.flatten(), y.flatten()), z.flatten(), (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
c = ax.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi,shading='auto')
```